# no booting device after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, acer

I have recently bought Acer Aspire E5-573G-57HR and decided to install Ubuntu instead of completing the installation of the preinstalled linpux linux. However, after succesfully completing the process, I was prompted to restart the computer. So when the computer turned on again (with USB still plugged in), I was given the same 4 options as before: see the preview of ubuntu/install it/manufactur installation/disk check...
If USB in plugged out, the computer says that there is no booting device.
What do I have to do to normally access the operating system?

Thank you for your help, Eva

Comment: Please take out the live USB after the restart.

Comment: maybe the installer didn't install grub, or it didn't configure it correctly? it happens sometimes.

Comment: Do you know if the system is using UEFI? If not, try [boot repair](http://askubuntu.com/a/182863/205638).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, this has to do with Secure Boot permissions:

1. Press F2 at boot and go into BIOS.
2. In security create a password for logging into bios. Then a bunch of options will become available to you.
3. One of the options is to pick or load a uefi file for secure boot.
4. Go into that and you should find grub in there.
5. It will add grub as a possible place to boot from using secure boot.
6. Save and restart and come back but this time go to the boot tab.

You should now see your newly added boot option.

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar challenge. Firstly I thought the installation was unsuccessful but rather it was successful and the issue is on the boot menu.
When you turn on your PC go to boot options, you should be able to see ubuntu listed there. If you select you are able to boot from the installed OS.

Hope it helps.